# Binned maximum likelihood estimate using R?

Tags: r, binning

I've seen many tutorial examples of **unbinned** maximum likelihood estimates being done using **R**. However, as of now I have yet to be able to find any examples of **binned** maximum likelihood estimates in R. While I can certainly try a different software, I am still interested to see whether it can be easily implemented in **R**.

As an example, say I am measuring the decay of some radioactive isotopes, and I have been provided with the number of events over 250 time bins, each of duration $\Delta t$. The number of events in each bin can be modelled by Poisson statistics with expected number for each bin being
$$
\bar{N}_{bin} = \Delta t N_0\lambda e^{-\lambda t_{bin}}
$$
so the log of the binned maximum likelihood function is given by
$$
\sum_{bin} \left( N_{bin} \ln(\bar{N}_{bin}) - \bar{N}_{bin} -\ln(N_{bin}!) \right)
$$
The parameters I want to estimate are $\lambda$ and $N_0$.

So again my question is whether this can be done relatively straightforward using **R**. Thanks!